# LearningModel.LoadFromStorageFileAsync faster_cnn / mask rcnn model "Unrecognized attribute: ceil_mode" exception

Tags: windows-machine-learning

I have downloaded the SqueezeNetObjectDetection sample. Got it running successfuly.

But then I have tried loading the faster rcnn model and got an exception with the message: "Unspecified error\r\n\r\nUnrecognized attribute: ceil_mode".
Same result when I tried loading the mask rcnn model.

Answer (score 0):

Your models might have higher opset version than WinML supports.
WinML supports up to opset 13 today from the doc [here](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/docs/Versioning.md).
A screenshot of the model properties would be helpful.

1. download [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron/releases/tag/v4.7.0)
2. Open your model with Netron and post the screenshot of model property